# Can't close a Window in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

So i'm following along a tutorial on electron and i'm stuck on this phase where i just cant get the close button to close the current window can anyone help ?

JavaScript code :

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const remote = electron.remote

const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn')

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
window.close();
})
```

Html code :

```
<body>
    <p class="notify">Notify me when BTC reaches..</p>

    <div class="row2">
        <div>
            <input id="notifyVal" placeholder="USD">
        </div>
        <button id="updateBtn">Update</button>
    </div>

        <a id="closeBtn">Close Window</a><br>

    </div>
    <script src="add.js"></script>
</body>
```

Css code :

```
body {
background:#DFDFDF;
color:#000;
overflow:hidden;
}

p.notify {
background:#C3C3C3;
margin:0;
padding: 20px;
text-transform:uppercase;
-webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.row2 {
width:100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
padding:20px;
}

input {
padding:12px;
}

#closeBtn {
cursor:pointer;
padding:20px;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I don't think that i have made mistake typing Because i even copied the code and still it didn't work i can create new windows but i cant close them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to nodeIntegration not being set to true in the main process. Since you are calling the require method from the renderer process (add.js) you may need to add nodeIntegration: true to your webPreferences in your main process (probably main.js). Try doing something like this:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500, 
    height: 400,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```

If there are any errors coming up in the console, let us know, they will help debug the issue.

Comment: Must be added either in main.js and index.js or whichever that calls BrowserWindow